# why after using ajaxToolkit ModalPopupExtender the ajax tab with grid stop to display data

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Im using a ajax tab panel and a ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender. In Ajax tab i place a gridview .  Problem is that On pageload i perform event like hide/show on page load the all page go to blank . But when i comment the code for modelpopup extender All tabs with data in grid is displaying properly .
for your review i am  giving my html page with code .

```
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
  <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server"  >
                                  <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="tabAss" runat="server" HeaderText="Assigned Alerts" >
                                  <ContentTemplate>
                                  // my asp gridview
                                  </ContentTemplate>
                                  </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>

  <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
                        <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopup"
                                PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground">

<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">   </asp:Panel>


                  </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code :

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            ModalPopupExtDesc.Hide();  // popup hide
            DescPanel.Visible = false; // panel hide
            if (Session["show"] != null)
            {
                ModalPopupExtender1.Show();
                Panel1.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ModalPopupExtender1.Hide();
                Panel1.Visible = false;
            }


        }
```

can you please tell me how can i find where the error in my panel so i am getting this problem